# Meaning of "False Positive"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

My question title itself is self explanatory. Can any explain what "false positive" means? I got this word usage from one of my clients in bug report.

Can anyone explain with usage in layman's language?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Can you please include the full sentence and explain in what context the phrase was used? It would be better if you could include your [own research efforts](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/false-positive) to find what it means and what you don't understand from it.  Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: In the context of software malware scans, a "false positive" is an instance where the software that is trying to detect infected files identifies a clean file (incorrectly) as infected. In other words, there is nothing wrong with the file, but the scanning software thinks that it contains a virus or Trojan horse or other type of malware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**False positive** means that a test detected the presence of something, but it was in fact not there.

For example, a mammogram and a sonogram strongly suggest the presence of  breast cancer, but a subsequent MRI-guided biopsy shows that the "tumor" is actually necrotized fat -- not cancer at all.  The signal from the mammogram and the sonogram were false positives.  The patient does not have breast cancer.

An argument against too frequent mammograms cites the dangers of false positives: they cause great anxiety and uncomfortable, expensive  biopsies.  **But a false positive is better than a false negative**.  A false negative is a result that says you are A-OK, no sign of disease X when actually you have disease X and are lulled into a false sense of well-being.

False positives disrupt your life for a week or two; false negatives can kill you if you don't double-check them.   If you want a reference, I'll supply one tomorrow afternoon, but it is too late in my time zone to do more work.  Until then, my reference is myself; I've a false positive and a false negative.

As for bugs, just translate what I said for cancer to bugs.

Comment: While a single false positive is probably better than a single false negative, don't forget, most diseases (and other problems that are tested for) are quite rare, so much so that false positives completely flood out not just the false negatives, but even the true positives.

Comment: Your explanation is very simple and easy to understand. Thanks @ab2

Comment: Also the effect of a false positive depends on the severity and risks of the treatment.